# Convert ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 using groovy

Tags: encoding, utf-8, groovy, iso-8859-1

i need to convert a ISO-8859-1 file to utf-8 encoding, without loosing content intormations...

i have a file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<HelloEncodingWorld>Üöäüßßß Test!!!</HelloEncodingWorld>
```

Not i want to encode it into UTF-8.
I tried following:

```
f=new File('c:/temp/myiso88591.xml').getText('ISO-8859-1')
ts=new String(f.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")
g=new File('c:/temp/myutf8.xml').write(ts)
```

didnt work due to String incompatibilities.
Then i read something about bytestreamreaders/writers/streamingmarkupbuilder and other...

then i tried

```
f=new File('c:/temp/myiso88591.xml').getText('ISO-8859-1')
mb = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder()
mb.encoding = "UTF-8"

new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream('c:/temp/myutf8.xml'),'utf-8') << mb.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    out << f
}
```

this was totally not that what i wanted..

I just want to get the content of an xml read with an ISO-8859-1 reader and then put it into a new (old) file... why this is so complicated :-/

The result should just be, and the file should be really encoded in utf-8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<HelloEncodingWorld>Üöäüßßß Test!!!</HelloEncodingWorld>
```

Thanks for any answers
Cheers

Comment: I haven't got the first idea about Groovy, but I assume that if you specify the encoding of the file for `File.getText`, it will be converted from that encoding to your internal encoding automatically. I.e. you probably don't need to do anything else as long as your internal encoding is set to use UTF-8. Somebody correct me if I'm off-track here. Alternatively, what are the exact errors you get?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
def f=new File('c:/data/myiso88591.xml').getText('ISO-8859-1')
new File('c:/data/myutf8.xml').write(f,'utf-8')
```

(I just gave it a try, it works :-)

same as in java: the libraries do the conversion for you... 
as deceze said: when you specify an encoding, it will be converted to an internal format (utf-16 afaik). When you specify another encoding when you write the string, it will be converted to this encoding.

But if you work with XML, you shouldn't have to worry about the encoding anyway because the XML parser will take care of it. It will read the first characters `<?xml` and determines the basic encoding from those characters. After that, it is able to read the encoding information from your xml header and use this.

Comment: `<?xml`? Isn't that the same in UTF-8 and ASCII and others? :)

Comment: Some UTF encodings start the file with a BOM. And in some encodings like ebcdic, the `<?xml` characters are not the same. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-guessing for details. It's very interesting and a good reason not to create your own code in order to guess the encoding.

Comment: Sorry but it is not right, that it really works. It is stored like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<HelloEncodingWorld>ÃÃ¶Ã¤Ã¼ÃÃÃ Test!!!</HelloEncodingWorld>`
and the encoding which is shown is still ISO-8859-1 (using notepad++) Maybe the first line forces the editor to show it as...ahh ok this was that case, omg, i already tried this way so often....but never realized that the data was encoded in utf 8 but shown as ansi... thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

Making it a little more Groovy, and not requiring the whole file to fit in memory, you can use the readers and writers to stream the file. This was my solution when I had files too big for plain old Unix `iconv(1)`.

```
new FileOutputStream('out.txt').withWriter('UTF-8') { writer ->
    new FileInputStream('in.txt').withReader('ISO-8859-1') { reader ->
        writer << reader
    }
}
```

- http://www.hjsoft.com/blog/link/A_Useful_Example_in_Java_Ruby_and_Groovy

Comment: Very groovy solution. I like the way you use the withReader/Writer. I tried it out myself and it worked great :)

Comment: Thanks @john-flinchbaugh that is what I was looking for! I used it to convert a huge file while he was downloaded from an FTP from `iso-8859-15` to `utf-8`. works great and the memory is safe ^^