# Parse XML using Groovy: Override charset in declaration and add XML processing instruction

Tags: groovy, character-encoding, xml-parsing, xml-declaration

My [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646974/parse-xml-using-groovy-how-do-i-keep-the-cdata-when-parsing-a-xml-file) have been answered, but that did just open up for further issues.

#### Example code

Using Groovy 2.0.5 JVM 1.6.0_31

```
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory

def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
            | <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Bp8DefaultView.xsl"?>
             |<root>
            |  <Settings>
            |    <Setting name="CASEID_SEQUENCE_SIZE">
            |      <HandlerURL>
            |        <![CDATA[ admin/MainWindow.jsp ]]>
            |      </HandlerURL>
            |    </Setting>
            |    <Setting name="SOMETHING_ELSE">
            |      <HandlerURL>
            |        <![CDATA[ admin/MainWindow.jsp ]]>
            |      </HandlerURL>
            |    </Setting>
            |  </Settings>
            |</root>'''.stripMargin()

def document = DOMBuilder.parse( new StringReader( xml ) )
def root = document.documentElement

// Edit: Added the line below 
def pi = document.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="Bp8DefaultView.xsl"');
// Edit #2: Added line below
document.insertBefore(pi, root)

use(DOMCategory) {
  root.Settings.Setting.each {
    if( it.'@name' == 'CASEID_SEQUENCE_SIZE' ) {
      it[ '@value' ] = 100
    }
  }
}

def outputfile = new File( 'c:/temp/output.xml' )
XmlUtil.serialize( root , new PrintWriter(outputfile))
// Edit #2: Changed from root to document.documentElement to see if that 
// would make any difference
println XmlUtil.serialize(document.documentElement)
```

#### Problem description

I'm trying to parse a XML-file exported from a third party tool, and before promoting it to stage and production I need to replace certain attribute values. That is all ok, but in addition I must keep the encoding and ref. to the stylesheet.

Since this is pretty static it is totally ok to have both the encoding and the stylesheet ref. definition in a property-file, meaning: I do not need first to find the declarations in the original file.

### Encoding in declaration issue

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7282669/512139) found here on StackOverFlow you can do

```
new File('c:/data/myutf8.xml').write(f,'utf-8')
```

I have also tried

```
XmlUtil.serialize( root , new GroovyPrintStream('c:/temp/output.txt', 'utf-16'))
```

but it did not solve the problem for me either. So I have not understood how to override the UTF-value.

### Processing instruction issue

Simply, how do I add

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Bp8DefaultView.xsl"?>
```

to the output?

*Update* - This can be done like this

```
def pi = document.createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="Bp8DefaultView.xsl"');
```

The processing instruction is being added like this, [this guideline](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0577.html) showed me, but still I do not get the output.

```
document.insertBefore(pi, root) // Fails
```

Comment: Seems like I should just not care about the encoding-issue, found this question [Why does createProcessingInstruction in VBA generate incomplete output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541174/why-does-createprocessinginstruction-in-vba-generate-incomplete-output)

Comment: Realizing that this question was a bit to ambiguous, I have created a new one only focusing on the processing instruction, see [/groovy-and-xml-not-able-to-insert-processing-instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781637/groovy-and-xml-not-able-to-insert-processing-instruction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All issues in this question has been answered in another question I raised, see  [Groovy and XML: Not able to insert processing instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781637/groovy-and-xml-not-able-to-insert-processing-instruction)

The trick is that I expected

```
document.documentElement
```

to contain the processing instruction. But that is wrong, documentElement is:

> ...This is a convenience attribute that allows direct access to the child node that is the document element of the document...

Where the processing instruction is just another child node. So what I instead had to use was either the *LSSerializer* or the *Transfomer*. See [Serialize XML processing instruction before root element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980033/serialize-xml-processing-instruction-before-root-element) for details.